handling kernel interrupt zynq 7020
I'm trying to handle a kernel interrupt
cortex-A9 processor, freeRTOS operating system
I tried to catch this interrupt using the following construction:
void __attribute__ ((interrupt ("IRQInterrupt")))
I also tried to override the standard handler Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_IRQ_INT, (Xil_ExceptionHandler)test_hendler,(void *) 0);
I initiate an interrupt by writing values to a non-existent address
my task is to have full control over the system and be able to handle all interrupts so that the program does not go into an endless loop
zynq 7020. vitis 2020.2
